# Change the order of folders in a URL string

Tags: string, url, mariadb, regexp-replace

I wonder if `REGEXP_REPLACE` in MariaDB allows to swap around the folders order in a URL string.

I would like for a url like this:

```
https://www.example.com/item1/item2/item3
```

To change the first folder after the domain to become the last:

```
https://www.example.com/item2/item3/item1
```

I can target with regex `item1` and the domain `https://www.example.com/` but not `item2` or `item3` as they keep changing

I am trying this

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(body, '(https://www.example.com)/(item1)/(item2)/(item3)', '\\1/\\3/\\4/\\2/')
```

But requires me to specify `item2` and `item3`

If I try to match any word in does not work

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(body, '(https://www.example.com)/(item1)/(\w+)/(\w+)', '\\1/\\3/\\4/\\2')
```

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew why did you remove the regex tag?

Comment: You have no regex problem in the question. If you tried some regex please add it to the question and explain what is wrong.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have a specific problem with regex now

Comment: But you yourself are using  `\\1` and not `\1` to define the backreference. Then why are you using `\w` and not `\\w`? It is a string literal problem at this point. Note that `\w` is not a good pattern to match URL subparts, but your example fits the `\w` approach. The regex [works](https://regex101.com/r/lBYO95/1), by the way.

Comment: If I use `\1` it prints the number literal

Comment: A `\1` text is a backreference. How you code the text inside your code depends on the programming language.

Comment: This is for MySQL (MariaDB) it seems to be working with `\\1` and `(\\w+)` Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution using:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(
  body, 
  '(https://www.example.com)/(item1)/(\\w+)/(\\w+)', 
  '\\1\/\\3\/\\4\/\\2\/'
);
```